# Pause jQuery ready events until multiple HTML DOM updates are finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ready

I am using jQuery to make AJAX submits and receive JSON replies containing multiple DOM IDs and corresponding HTML fragments that I need to update. Thus, I do multiple `jQuery.html` calls like `$('#id1').html('...'); $('#id2').html('...');`.

For every fragment containing a `ready` handler like `$(function(){...});`, the event is immediately triggered. I'd prefer to call it once after all updates were made.

Is there any way to do that?

From what I've read so far, [a jQuery.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) could be used to manually trigger the `ready` event. But I'd need to save and restore the current handlers or postpone event delivery by overwriting the jQuery internals somehow. The latter is something that I'd like to avoid, maybe there's some best practice I don't know yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `holdReady` function.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/

Answer (score 1):

I would start by moving the js you have in your views into external js files where they can be invoked from the ajax callback functions.

As you are finding out in-page ready events can soon leave you feeling out of control and become very hard to maintain. Regain control, namespace your js up into logical sections and lose the ready reliance.

There is no need for ready statements if you include your js before the closing body tag. The best advice I can give is to start being explicit in your apps lifecycle about what js gets called when, rather than relying on the well over abused ready statement.

Rebecca Murphy has written some very good articles/[presentations](http://www.slideshare.net/rmurphey/building-large-jquery-applications) about this.

Comment: redsquare, I agree that this may become a mess very quickly. However, I like the fact that the HTML fragments become "self-contained" and the caller doesn't have to know what else to call. I'll try to follow that path first, but I'll keep your warning in mind. Maybe I'll give the same warning in a couple of weeks... ;-)

Comment: @digitalbreed By having scripts all over your views they are not cached or reusable. Also what happens when other widgets on the page outside of the dynamic content become interested in the fact something has changed. How do you let them know? Do you then cram this logic in the view...but what if the other widget doesnt exist...pub/sub is also your friend. I came unstuck on a good few apps before I found a better way of doing it. Hope it helps you.